# How to type a conditional render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to type conditional rendering but it gives error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type 'types'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'types'.` The render works when everything is "any".

```
interface types {
  '0': JSX.Element;
  '1': JSX.Element;
  '2': JSX.Element;
}

export default function Economy(props: any) {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0)

  const render = () => {
    const component: types = {
      '0': <Home />,
      '1': <Create />,
      '2': <Detail />,
    }
    return component[step]
  }
return (
   {render()}
)
```

Can anyone help me understand how to type this conditional render?

i need to understand how to type this conditional render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `step` has a type of `number`, which can't be used to index `types`, since `types` only have `1,2,3`. So you can manually type `step` to be a `keyof types`:

```
const [step, setStep] = useState<keyof types>(0)
```

Since `step` is a number you will also need the keys:

```
interface types {
  0: JSX.Element;
  1: JSX.Element;
  2: JSX.Element;
}
 const component: types = {
      0: <Home />,
      1: <Create />,
      2: <Detail />,
    }
 return component[step] // no error
```

Comment: thanks! Got it, it worked correctly without type error

Answer (score 0):

When indexing an object you'll have to use the [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) operator.
From the TypeScript Docs:

> The keyof type operator
> The keyof operator takes an object type and produces a string or numeric literal union of its keys.

```
interface types {
  '0': JSX.Element;
  '1': JSX.Element;
  '2': JSX.Element;
}

export default function Economy(props: any) {
  const [step, setStep] = useState<keyof types>("0")

  const render = () => {
    const component: types = {
      '0': <Home />,
      '1': <Create />,
      '2': <Detail />,
    }
    return component[step]
  }
return (
   {render()}
)
```